# Java, "a[1] *= a[1] = b[n + 1]" not working as expected?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, multiplication, assignment-operator

So as the title shows, I've got a function that uses a temporary array, and I want to write a value into it from another array, and then multiply the two value with itself.

Example:

```
float[] a = {0, 0}

a[0] *= a[0] = b[n    ];
a[1] *= a[1] = b[n + 1];
```

I would expect the above would do the following:

```
a[0] = b[n    ];
a[0] *= a[0]; //(aka: a[0] = a[0] * a[0])

a[1] = b[n + 1];
a[1] *= a[1];
```

Though that behavior doesn't seem to be whats happening. Instead it seems just multiply whatever the original value held in "a" was with whatever value was held in "b" like so:

```
a[0] = a[0] * b[n    ];
a[1] = a[1] * b[n + 1];
```

It was always my understanding that whatever comes after the "=" is evaluated first, as seen when you do:

```
float a, b;
a = b = 5;
//"a" and "b" both equal "5" now.
```

Being that that is the case, would it not show that my original example should work?

Can anyone explain whats going on and why this code doesn't work as intended?

Comment: At first glance this seemed to be one of those newbie questions, but thinking about it you have a point. However I wouldn't ever want to see this in production code. Rule of thumb: write it as `a[0]=b[n]*b[n]` which is much easier to read. Code like that was only useful back in the days when the compiler had to fit in about 30k of memory and you might save some cpu cycles by doing some tricky fiddling because compilers were not optimizing.
Don't have the time now, but in Java it should all be set down in the spec (whereas in C I think it would be either undefined or implementation defined).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answers so far are not correct. What comes into play is the evaluation of compound expressions like `a *= b`. In short, the value of **the left hand side is computed before the right hand side**. From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) (emphasis mine):

> At run time, the expression is evaluated in one of two ways.
>
> If the left-hand operand expression is not an array access expression,
>   then:
>
> First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. If
>   this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression
>   completes abruptly for the same reason; the right-hand operand is not
>   evaluated and no assignment occurs.
>
> Otherwise, **the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the
>   right-hand operand is evaluated**. If this evaluation completes
>   abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the
>   same reason and no assignment occurs.
>
> Otherwise, the saved value of the left-hand variable and the value of
>   the right-hand operand are used to perform the binary operation
>   indicated by the compound assignment operator. If this operation
>   completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly
>   for the same reason and no assignment occurs.
>
> Otherwise, the result of the binary operation is converted to the type
>   of the left-hand variable, subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13)
>   to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value
>   set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the variable.

In your example:

```
a[0] *= a[0] = b[n    ];
```

1. value of `a[0]` is computed and stored in say `tmp`
2. `a[0] = b[n]` is evaluated, giving the value of `b[n]` (and changing the value of `a[0]` to `b[n]`)
3. `tmp * a[0]` is computed
4. the result of the last step is assigned to `a[0]`

So, what you get is effectively `a[0] *= b[n]`.

**EDIT:** About the confusion about right-to-left-*evaluation* of assignments: I did not find that terminology used in the JLS, and IMHO it is not correct (although it is used in the Java tutorials). It is called right-**associative* assThe JLS says this about assignments:

> There are 12 assignment operators; all are syntactically
>   right-associative (they group right-to-left). Thus, a=b=c means
>   a=(b=c), which assigns the value of c to b and then assigns the value
>   of b to a.

Comment: so if the left side in `a *= b` is evaluated, evaluated fist, whatever the value of `a` is at the time would be caches, then the 2nd part of the expression would be run, then when it that part is resolved, it uses the previously cached version of `a` to finish the assignment which finally gets stored in the actual `a` variable?

Comment: What I don't understand is, why this is called "right to left"-evaluation. Because the value on the left side of the assignment is evaluated before the value on the right side (and saved), isn't it?

Comment: @ArchLinuxTux It seems that the JLS wants the right side assignment to be treated as an expression and not a real assignment (hence the LHS value is saved).  The "real" assignment is the `*=` happening last.

Comment: @ArchLinuxTux IMHO that's simply wrong in the Java tutorials. In fact, the JLS doesn't say that assignments are evaluated "right to left". It says "right-associative", which is the correct term.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

So what is happening in your case of `a[0] *= a[0] = b[n    ];` is that you assign `a[0]` the value of `b[n]` and then you multiply the original `a[0]` by that new value. So your expression is effectively `a[0] *= b[n]`.

Personally, I don't use an assignment operator twice on a single line, it can be confusing to read.

Comment: If you don't evaluate the LHS first, how can you use the LHS's original value later? I think the part in the Java tutorial you linked to is a bit oversimplifying what's really going on. In compound assignment LHS is evaluated first, then RHS is evaluated, the computation is done, and then the variable on the LHS is assigned the result of the computation. I think what the paragraph you cited was trying to make clear is simply that `a=b=c` results in the value of `c` being assigned to both `a` and `b`.

Comment: I agree there is a simplification, it's not clear how the LHS `a[0]` is different to the RHS `a[0]`, but the RHS `a[0] = b[n]` is clearly evaluated first, followed by the evaluation `a[0](old) *= a[0](new)`. In the expression `a = b = c`, first `b = c` and then `a = b`.

Comment: First `a[0]` is evaluated and stored as `a[0](old)`. The rest is correct.

Comment: I see what you mean. I was trying to emphasize the order of assignments, rather than the fact that the LHS value is stored.

Answer (score 2):

Assignment operators (unlike most other operators) are evaluated from *right* to *left* in Java ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)).  This means that the following:

```
a[0] *= a[0] = b[n];
```

is actually evaluated as:

```
a[0] *= (a[0] = b[n]);
```

The quantity in parentheses is an assignment, and returns the value `b[n]`, but does not change the value of `a[0]`.  Then, the following final assignment is made:

```
a[0] = a[0] * b[n]
```

Both `*=` and `=` are assignment operators, and have the same level of precedence.  So in this case, the right to left rule applies.

Comment: I think this doesn't really make it clear why `a[0] *= (a[0] = b[n])` should be the same as `a[0] *= b[n]`, since one could expect that after evaluating `(a[0] = b[n])`, the value of `a[0]` was set to `b[n]` and thus result in `a[0] = b[n]*b[n]`.

Comment: @Axel yeah, thats what I thought would happen, I even tried what you mentioned, before posting this question, "a[0] *= (a[0] = b[n])" to see if the brackets had any effect, and they ended up being compiled out when the .java was converted to a .class file. Was defiantly left scratching my head.

Comment: @Axel I have explained what happens, but I might be slightly off.  I can make this a Wiki post if you want to contribute.  Basically, the assignment on the RHS itself returns `b[n]`, and then another assignment is made to `a[0]`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So whats effectively happening is the value of (a[0] = b[n]) is being held in an "invisible" temporary variable, because the *= operator essentially cannot read and write to itself at the same time?

Comment: @HexCrown I'm not expert enough to answer one way or the other.  My observations, from testing, is that the assignment itself returns the value of the RHS, but the assignment does not "stick" to the variable on the LHS.  Which seems counter intuitive to me, but hey, this is Java.

Comment: Hey, it's all in the spec. Read my answer. value of LHS is computed first, so the assignment on the RHS has no effect on the result.

Answer (score 0):

A key point that doesn't seem to have been pointed out in the answers yet is that `*=` isn't merely an assignment operator, but rather a *compound* assignment operator.

[The language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) says that the following are equivalent:

```
E1 op= E2
    <=>
E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))
```

where `op=` is something like `*=`, `+=` etc.

As such:

```
a[0] *= a[0] = b[n    ];
```

is equivalent to:

```
a[0] = a[0] * (a[0] = b[n]);
```

and the `a[0]` is evaluated before the `(a[0] = b[n])`, because of the [left-to-right evaluation order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7).

So:

- This reads the value from `a[0]` (call this "`A`")
- It reads the value from `b[n]` (call this "`B`")
- It assigns `B` to `a[0]`  (*)
- And then multiplies `A * B` (call this "`C`")
- And then stores `C` back in `a[0]`.

So yes, this is equivalent to multiplying whatever is in `a[0]` by `b[n]`, because the step marked (*) above is redundant: the value assigned there is never read before it is reassigned.